# What can cause cuda folder to get erased?

Tags: nvidia, cuda

The CUDA folder (`/usr/local/cuda`) "disappears" from time to time and I need to go through the installation again. What I usually install is cuda 8.0 and create a link to `/usr/local/cuda` ..

This happens without me touching the computer at all. Is there any automatic installation or update that could cause that?

I have Ubuntu 16.04

If you need more details do not hesitate to ask me.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know about your system. But this also happen with  me. I my case, it happen when. I have upgraded nvidia-384 to nvidia-387.

Comment: Each CUDA version installs and depends on a specific driver version. Installing a newer driver version uninstalls CUDA.

Comment: @MichaelBay thanks! I see I am not able to add both in one single comment

Comment: Where can I check the compatible driver version? The strange thing is that it did not happen instantaneously but some days after installing the driver. Could that happen?